# Retrieve high views per day questions with few answers

Tags: sql, sql-server, stackexchange

I've been messing around with the SE Data Explorer and I've come up with a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/512694/high-views-per-day-questions-with-few-answers) that basically returns information about questions that have a high number of views per day, that have few or no answers.

```
SELECT 
      TOP 500
      Question.ViewCount,
      DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(date,Question.CreationDate), CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) ) AS Days ,    
      Question.Id AS [Post Link],
      (Question.ViewCount / DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(date,Question.CreationDate), CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) )) AS ViewsPerDay,
      Question.AnswerCount,
      (SELECT MAX (Answers.Score )
       FROM POSTS "Answers"
       WHERE Answers.ParentId = Question.Id
       AND   Answers.PostTypeId = 2
      ) "Highest Answer Score",
      Question.Tags
 FROM
      POSTS "Question"
WHERE Question.PostTypeId = 1 
AND   Question.acceptedanswerid is null
AND   DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(date,Question.CreationDate), CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) ) > 10
AND   (Question.ViewCount / DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(date,Question.CreationDate), CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) )) > 5
ORDER BY
    AnswerCount ASC,
    "Highest Answer Score" ASC,
    ViewsPerDay DESC
```

It's been a while since I used SQL directly in anger, so any feedback's welcome.

I particularly don't like the way `DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(date,Question.CreationDate), CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) )` is repeated in both the `SELECT` and the `WHERE` clauses, so I'd like some way of aliasing the check if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Overall

I think your query is pretty nicely written and returns useful information.

---

Use some variables to refer to repeated values, for example, the `GETDATE()` reference could just be declared as a variable at the top and reused throughout.

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME2 = GETDATE();
```

You could also use variables to eliminate some magic numbers, such as the `Posts.PostTypeId` for questions and answers.

---

You might want to add a field to indicate when the question was actually posted. A day count is all fair and well, but knowing the actual post date might be good information as well.

```
SELECT 
  /* ...*/ 
  Question.CreationDate AS DatePosted
```

You might want to rename the `Days` column to something a bit more descriptive, like `DaysSinceFirstPosted` or just `DaysOld`.

---

Use `day` instead of `dd`, they work the same but `day` makes the code easier to read.

You also don't need to convert datetime fields to date fields for calculations to work correctly, it's all factored in for you already, e.g.:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, Question.CreationDate, @now) AS DaysSinceFirstPosted
```

---

`ViewsPerDay` would be better named as `AverageViewsPerDay` based on your calculations.

---

> ```
> SELECT 
>     /* ... */
>       (SELECT MAX (Answers.Score)
>        FROM POSTS "Answers"
>        WHERE Answers.ParentId = Question.Id
>        AND   Answers.PostTypeId = 2
>       ) "Highest Answer Score",
> ```

This would make more sense as a normal table join rather than an inline subquery:

```
SELECT
    /* ... */
    MAX(Answers.Score) AS [HighestAnswerScore],
    /* ... */
FROM
    Posts AS [Question]
    LEFT JOIN Posts AS [Answers]
        ON Answers.ParentId = Question.Id
        AND Answers.PostTypeId = @answer
WHERE 
    /* ... */
```

---

If you plan on using quoted identifiers as you did, you would want to declare `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;` at the top of your query. SE Data Explorer must have that set by default, yet it's not the case for some other databases. I personally find it more practical to use default square brackets for identifiers.

---

With all of the above applied, here is the [new query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/512808):

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME2 = GETDATE();
DECLARE @question INT = 1;
DECLARE @answer INT = 2;
SELECT TOP 500
    Question.CreationDate AS QuestionPosted,
    Question.ViewCount AS QuestionViews,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, Question.CreationDate, @now) AS DaysSinceFirstPosted,    
    Question.Id AS [Post Link],
    Question.ViewCount / DATEDIFF(DAY, Question.CreationDate, @now) AS AverageViewsPerDay,
    Question.AnswerCount,
    MAX(Answers.Score) AS HighestAnswerScore,
    Question.Tags
FROM
    Posts AS [Question]
    LEFT JOIN Posts AS [Answers]
        ON Answers.ParentId = Question.Id
        AND Answers.PostTypeId = @answer
WHERE 
    Question.PostTypeId = @question
    AND Question.AcceptedAnswerId is null
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, Question.CreationDate, @now) > 10
    AND (Question.ViewCount / DATEDIFF(DAY, Question.CreationDate, @now)) > 5
GROUP BY
    Question.CreationDate,
    Question.ViewCount,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, Question.CreationDate, @now),
    Question.Id,
    Question.ViewCount / DATEDIFF(DAY, Question.CreationDate, @now),
    Question.AnswerCount,
    Answers.Score,
    Question.Tags
ORDER BY
    AnswerCount ASC,
    HighestAnswerScore ASC,
    AverageViewsPerDay DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think the quoted identifiers have bitten me in the past, but it's been the standard approach where I've worked, maybe Oracle has different default behaviour/configurations.  The only thing I'm not sure about is the large `GROUP BY` clause you've introduced, presumably as  a result of moving the sub query into a join.  Does this approach give benefits that offset the need to maintain the selected columns in both places?

Comment: The added `GROUP BY` clause doesn't have any specific benefits at the moment, in fact it's slightly slower. It would have some benefits if you needed to add new aggregates to the query.

Answer (score 2):

**Consider Your Audience**

The columns that are returned by the query don't appear to have been selected in any particular order.  This is OK for queries that are being run by a client, for example from a programming language however the primary client for the stack query is likely through the website.  On a lower size screen format (such as mobile phones), this means that the left side of the returned data set is the most important and should contain the columns that will most influence the users actions.

'Post Link', 'Tags', 'Highest Answer Score' and then 'Views Per Day' seem like the most important columns in that order.

**Consider Closed Questions**

The query is aimed at finding high view questions that might need some kind of action (close votes, new answers, or votes for existing answers).  These actions are most relevant to open questions, however currently the query doesn't exclude closed questions.  The easiest way to exclude closed questions is by adding an additional item to the where clause:

```
AND   Question.ClosedDate is null
```